# Jasmine Test Cases for up and down arrow keyboard events

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit test cases for keyboard events for an autocomplete component. Below function is called when user press keyup and keydown to select values from dropdown:

```
onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent){
    if(event.which !== 40 && event.which !== 38){
        return;
    }

    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.which === 40 && this.arrowkeylocation < this.suggestionArray.length - 1) {
        // Arrow Down
        this.arrowkeylocation++;
        this.textSearch = this.suggestionArray[this.arrowkeylocation].title;
    } else if (event.which === 38 && this.arrowkeylocation > 0) {
        // Arrow Up
        this.arrowkeylocation--;
        this.textSearch = this.suggestionArray[this.arrowkeylocation].title;
    }      
}
```

Below are the test cases which does not work:

```
it('should call onKeyDown 40 event', () => {
    const keyevent = {keyCode: 40};
    component.suggestionArray = [suggest,suggest];
    inputEl.triggerEventHandler('keydown',keyevent);
    expect(component.onKeyDown).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.arrowkeylocation).toEqual(0);  
expect(component.textSearch).toEqual(component.suggestionArray[0].title);        
});
```

Here arrowkeylocation is counter initilaized to -1 to autocomplete text box value when user press keyup or keydown.
suggestionArray is autocomplete dropdown values.

Comment: What's your error exactly ?

Comment: you can create a spy for the `window.keydown` and call the spy

Comment: @trichetriche It is showing Expected -1 to equal 0. at line expect(component.arrowkeylocation).toEqual(0).

Comment: @Aravind How it will be different to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, `arrowkeylocation` is at -1 but your expect it to be at zero. Check your initial variable values to correct this issue.

Comment: @trichetriche I have explicitly set arrowkeylocation to -1 but still its same error. Any idea?

Comment: If you set it a -1, you must expect -2 ... Just read your own code !

Comment: @trichetriche For keycode 40 arrowkeylocation should be incremented so it should be 0 and not -2.

Comment: No, if the `which` property is at 40 it should increment. Since you provide the `arrowkeylocation` and not the `which`, it just returns at the first instruction.

Comment: Damn I wrote -2 instead of -1, sorry about the confusion !

Comment: Thanks it worked after setting which property.